# AWS RDS PROXY high availability across two different regions

Tags: amazon-rds-proxy

thanking you for your responses.
I have one "rds proxy" connected to "aurora rds primary" in one region and another "rds proxy" connected to the other "aurora rds stanby or secondary" but in a different region.

Here comes the challenge: If the first "rds proxy" goes down

1. How to manage so that the "secondary rds proxy becomes active" and is transparent to applications?
2. Is there some architectural pattern to have "rds proxy" in high availability across two different regions.

Comment: My understanding is Aurora will fallover to another region when the primary write region has stopped working, and Route53 will failover to the region responding too and your application in the backup region has set to use the fallback region's AuroraDB as the DB endpoint. RDS Proxy is a regional service, it solves the delaying problem when MultiZA failover happens, not really for regional failover